# have never thought vs had never known

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Peter and Sarah don't like each other in my impression. But suppose someone has just told me that Peter would marry Sarah. In surprise, I said,

> **I've** never thought of that. (I think had is wrong, because now I think it's still hard to imagine.)

> **I'd** never known that. (I think have is wrong, because now I know that. )

Do you think these two sentences are correct?

Comment: "I would never have expected that!"

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to know whether those two sentences in my OP are correct.

Comment: They are not correct. We use _never thought of_ to refer to something like an idea or a different way of solving a problem, not a piece of news. You might say "I didn't know that", but that doesn't convey the sense that you found the news surprising.

Comment: Is it right to say "I've never expected that"?

Comment: No, the idiom is "I would never have expected that", as I suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll use the idiom. By the way, is my suggestion grammatical, if not natural?

Comment: Yes - see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+never+expected+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20never%20expected%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20have%20never%20expected%20that%3B%2Cc0)